# How do we convert HTML page to a pdf file using jspdf including images and css styles?

Tags: jspdf

Below code will generate a pdf which contains only text and does not include any images or styles.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();       
      var source = document.getElementById("dividofhtml");
       doc.fromHTML(source,15,15);
       doc.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will include images and css styling in pdf.

```
html2canvas($("#up"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
                doc.save('text.pdf');
            }
        });
```